# How can I get rid of profile music on Tagged?

Tags: tagged.com

How can I prevent the profile music on Tagged user profiles from playing?

If I have to set up privoxy or some such to block the music files, I will, but I'd rather not go to such effort for what *should* be a simple configuration option.  Then on the other hand Tagged's UI pretty well sucks across the board (makes MySpace seem friendly), so I wouldn't be surprised if it's not possible.

Comment: I know my tags suck, but I can't create a 'tagged' tag until I earn 15 more rep.